# Flash Overlapping HTML. CSS Problem In IE?

Tags: html, css, flash

HELP, this is a very unique problem and I can't for the life of me figure it out.

My flash content is overlapping the HTML above it.

This only happens if I've just launched IE after being restarted and goes away once I refresh the page.  I even added a jQuery `$(document).ready` function that sets a margin between the html and the flash content to add 1px of space when the page is loaded.  It's so hard to figure out, because once I refresh the page, it goes away.

Any input GREATLY appreciated.

Here is the site.

http://www.californiaremodels.com

(This only happens in IE)

here is a [screen shot](http://californiaremodels.com/overlap.jpg) of the problem.

########### SOLVED ###################### SOLVED

I set the flash  output as a javascript var (actually json_encoded PHP output) and on document load inserted the object into the "flashContent" div with the `jQuery.(document).ready` event.

Thank you to Andy Shellam!!

Comment: It doesn't appear to be happening in IE 7...

Comment: @jball.  It happens like one out of 4-5 times which is what is killing me.

Comment: Intermittent problems are the worst... I didn't notice any obvious reason in the markup.

Comment: Have you tried loading your flash content using jQuery?  I.e. set your div width/height in your HTML with a "this requires javascript/flash" placeholder, then have jQuery load the OBJECT into the div on page load.  This way cures IE7's annoying "click here to activate this control" issue - may be a similar issue.

Comment: @Andy, trying that now... interesting you would mention that because I actually have PHP build out the flash content.  I'm going to json_encode the output as a javascript var and then load that in via jQuery at run time... fingers crossed...

Comment: @Andy... IT WORKED!!!!  If you want to add your answer I'll give you the check mark.

Comment: @Jascha - Cool that was just a shot in the dark!  I've added it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried loading your flash content using jQuery? I.e. set your div width/height in your HTML with a "this requires javascript/flash" placeholder, then have jQuery load the OBJECT into the div on page load. This way cures IE7's annoying "click here to activate this control" issue - may be a similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

It may be due to the fact that you're floating that DIV that holds the flash content. It shouldn't matter, but sometimes IE gets hinky about such things. Try taking off the float and see if that cures the problem. If it does, create a non-floating workaround.

Answer (score 0):

looks like it is the -4px of margin top you have that is creating the problem